# Adding css on the end of the body inside a wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I wonder how can I add a css block on the end of the body whenever a shortcode is rendered.

Comment: Do you mean: include css/js only if a shortcode is present on the page?

Comment: Hi, sorry but now. Because the shortcode is rendered only when inserted into the page content. The idea is to avoid having several blocoks of style around the dom.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. In general an example would help. Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html check this link out, I think it should give you a good idea on how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
function my_shortcode(){
    echo 'My Shortcode';
}
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode');

function add_css_when_shortcode_present() {
    global $post;
    if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'my_shortcode') && !is_admin() ) {
        echo '<style>'."\n";
        echo ".body {\n\tdisplay: none;\n}\n";
        echo '</style>';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_css_when_shortcode_present');
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your example.
Unfortunately I need to generate the css inside the shortcode function in order to get the user-entered attributes and create css parameters.

Comment: you can add CSS on shortcode output itself, you can add a class on your shortcode and and target that class in CSS, there are so many ways to do that, the question is how do you want to do it,

Comment: Hi, currently what I have is: I add a class to the shortcode and then I echo the <style> with the shortcode html. But I think that this is not good practice.I liked to call a filter / function and send the style for the function add everything together at the end of the body.